# Why does hash a not return the same result for a[:b] vs a["b"]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key

I realize symbol keys in a hash are immutable whereas string keys are mutable, but I still don't understand why that would cause these results ...

```
[5] pry(main)> a[:b] = "c"
=> "c"
[6] pry(main)> a["b"]
=> nil
[7] pry(main)> a[:b]
=> "c"
```

Shouldn't `"a[:b]"` get turned into `a["b"]` under the hood?

Comment: Why do you expect one object to be silently converted into another “under the hood”? The question sounds to me like “should not `42` to be turned into `[:foo, :bar]` under the hood?”.

Comment: Maybe I should have put, what is happening under the hood?  Is the key ":b" treated as an immutable string, "b"?

Comment: Basically, `"b"` and `:b` have nothing in common. I mean, _nothing_.

Comment: @Dave no, it's not, `:b` is treated like `:b`.

Comment: Maybe you have a different point of view since the use of Rails and its `with_indifferent_access` method? But no, I think there's no case where `"b"` is equal to `:b`. They're pretty much different objects.

Comment: BTW 'string keys are mutable' - not always, you can easily make your strings immutable by `freeze` method. There's even magic comment - `# frozen_string_literal: true`, that causes implicit immutability of any string literal put in the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't, `:b` is a different object than `'b'`, so unless `a` is a hash with indifferent access, `a[:b]` will most likely return different result than `a['b']`.

BTW althouth Ruby is in fact dynamically typed, it's also quite strongly typed - implicit type conversion occurs rather rarely here.

Comment: Thank you.  I know it's different due to the results I put in my question.  My question is why is it different?  What's happening under the hood with the hash keys that are causing different hash values?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be different?

Comment: Because I read the key ":b" is treated as an immutable string "b" under the hood.  Is that what is happening?

Comment: @Dave no, not really. It's more like 'scalar value object used as identifiers, mapping immutable string to fixed internal value', not 'immutable string' itself.

Comment: Oh!  Ok, I'll have to read up on scalar value objects but that explains it.  Thx!

Comment: @Dave If you want the behaviour as defined in your question you have to use [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) which can be achieved through `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({a: 1, b: 2})` or `{a: 1, b: 2}.with_indifferent_access`.